# iOS 7 MKMapView : Drawing a path with 2 alternate colors.

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mkmapview, mapkit

On a `MKMapView` I need to draw multiple paths. Each "Mega"-path has it's own color.

Each "Mega"-path is divided in subpath. Some time a subpath is shared by 2 Mega-path.

I would like to draw these sub-path with some dashed alternate colors.

Any idea how to do it ?

What I have now can only draw one color :

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if(overlay == self.routeLine){

        MKPolylineRenderer* lineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
        lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lineView.lineWidth = 5;

        return lineView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set lineView.lineDashPattern and lineView.lineDashPhase as per

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013136-CH1-SW21

to get a dashed line.

What I had done in my app was drawn the path with a solid stroke, then drawn over it again with the dashed line to get alternating colors.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is to subclass the renderer and do the Core Graphics drawing yourself manually into the provided `CGContext`.